# Does a C++ or C# library exist for converting CSS/HTML/jQuery code to C++ or C# code?

Tags: c#, jquery, c++, html, css

I am working on designing a GUI for a software that will be written in C++ or C#. My partner and I would like to test out the GUI in the browser first and then import to C++ or C#.

Does a C++ or C# library exist for converting CSS/HTML/jQuery code to C++ or C# code?

Comment: No. How would that even work?

Comment: for prototyping try a tool like  http://balsamiq.com/ mockups

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to limit yourself with some of the quirks of HTML/CSS when mocking something up for C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the paradigms for developing for web applications and desktop applications are completely incompatible.

If you don't have experience developing UI for a desktop application, the prototyping phase is a great time to get that experience.

I always find it easiest to create prototypes in Visual Studio, and I also rely on [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/) for testing small blocks of xaml.

Comment: Greg Sansom What programs do you recommend for prototyping GUIs for desktop apps?

Answer (score 2):

**If you're interested targeting WPF/C#, [here is a tool](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2313.aspx) that converts between HTML/CSS and XAML.** It doesn't support ever possible tag or markup scenario, but for basic HTML/CSS it does seem to work.

**Personally, I would avoid this as a prototyping approach, and would go straight to using WPF or Silverlight with a tool like Expression Blend** (or even Visual Studio). With the prototyping features already available in these tools, there's really no reason to mock up such UIs in a browser with HTML. I also wouldn't trust that such a conversion would ever preserve all of the behavior quirks and nuances that you would desire.

Prototyping is also the point where you are beginning to establish assumption about the range of UI interactions you intend to support .. why complicate that by using the wrong tool? If your goal is to quickly communicate a possible UI layout to a customer, I suggest you use Visio or a paper mockup as premature interactivity could actually get in the way of a meaningful discussion of user experience. You don't want such discussions to get bogged down in fonts, colors, and pixels.

Comment: Ok thank you LBushkin. I only mentioned CSS/HTML because that is what I am used to.